# CSS3 animation behaves unexpectedly

Tags: html, css

I have been working on an animation of a ball rolling and falling off an edge. First, I made a version which just rolls, and then stops. Working fine. But then, when I added the falling animation to the same code, it doesn't roll it, and I can't do anything about it. 
Here is the first snippet:

```
@-webkit-keyframes roll{
    0% {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(480px) rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

then the second:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rollandfall{
0% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(480px) rotate(360deg);
}
85% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: translate(480px, 400px) rotate(360deg);
}
95% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(480px, 380px);
}
100% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: translate(480px, 400px);
}
}
```

(I know it's only for safari and chrome, but I want to finish it before making it accessible in every browser)
And [here](http://attilah.bplaced.net/experiments/arrow.html) is the link to the animation.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
It seems it wasn't exactly clear what I want it to do, so 
[here](http://attilah.bplaced.net/experiments/arrow2.html) you can check out what the first snippet does.

Comment: It does work for me on latest chrome on osx mavericks.

Comment: I use Safari, on the same os, and it does't work for me. I will try chrome. How is this possible?

Comment: Wierd shit, works for me in safari as well. It is when hovering the ball it should work right? There is not some caching problem you've got?

Comment: Wait, you mean it rolls the ball when it's moving horizontally? It should rotate it by 360 degrees.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The ball rolls away to the right when I hover it, and then it falls down with a bounce. Just as the code above is expected to work :) Try to run in incognito-mode or delete your browser cache.

Comment: Yes, that's what it doesn't do for me. Thanks for the tip, I will try.

Comment: The ball doesn't roll, it 'slides'...

Comment: @fguchelaar OK, then it is not the problem of mine. I will edit the question so it will be more clear what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way, seems to 'chain' the animations:

```
#goRight img:hover{
    -webkit-animation: roll 1s, fall 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes roll{
    0% {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(480px) rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fall{
    0% {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(480px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(480px) translateY(400px);
    }
}
```

Much cleaner!

Comment: Well, this works... So thank you! But I'm curious what I did wrong in the original version.

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I'm no expert in CSS3, but after some tweaking, this seems to work... ish.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rollandfall{
    0% {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    5% {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(48px) rotate(36deg);
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(240px) rotate(180deg);
    }
    30% {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(284px) rotate(216deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(480px) rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-transform: translate(480px, 400px) rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

I've created some smaller increments, to tell the engine it should animate in a certain direction; if you put 180deg half way, it seems to roll in the opposite direction.

Needs some tweaking for a smoother animation, probably.

Comment: Eww, this is what I tried to avoid. I understand, that this works, kinda, but I want to know what I am doing wrong in this one.